# How to convert XLSX file containing (images ,barcode font) into PDF file?

Tags: java

I want to convert excel file having .xlsx extension which contains images and cell containing values in general format into PDF file.

Comment: It' s better to provide some information about what you have tried so far, what effort you have put, or what research you did.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) as in [this](http://thinktibits.blogspot.com.tr/2012/12/Convert-XLSX-to-PDF-Java-Example-Program.html) example.